# Mapbox GL cluster feature support other source types?

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox GL cluster feature as https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/

Does this feature work on source type other than geojson? such as vector tile pbf type ? Is there any workaround to make it to work with vector tile source type?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it seems that the cluster feature is only supported by a GeoJSONSource. Internally it uses [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster), so you can probably use it to implement a custom solution.

You can have a look at [GeoJSONSource](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/c7a954334794bd7e0f5258d75815b2b2cee67d50/js/source/geojson_source.js#L137):

```
superclusterOptions: {
    maxZoom: Math.min(options.clusterMaxZoom, this.maxzoom - 1) || (this.maxzoom - 1),
    extent: EXTENT,
    radius: (options.clusterRadius || 50) * scale,
    log: false
}
```

and [GeoJSONWorkerSource](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/2924b910d7a9a0a12e0d71bd0771f7529acfade8/js/source/geojson_worker_source.js#L130):

```
if (params.cluster) {
   callback(null, supercluster(params.superclusterOptions).load(data.features));
} else {
   callback(null, geojsonvt(data, params.geojsonVtOptions));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample code or fiddle? I need to use a vector tile source in clusters.